# Get size of the bucket based on storage classes in Google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to get the size of the bucket based on storage class . I've added rules to bucket to change the storage class of the files based on age of the file. 
I've used below commands

```
gsutil du -sh gs://[bucket-name] 

To get Meta-data : 
gsutil ls -L gs://[bucket-name] 

To set ACL to bucket 

gsutil lifecycle set life-cycle.json gs://[bucket-name]
```

Please any one help on this to resolve my issue

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

I have filed a Feature Request for this on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/119989059). In the meantime, the code below can be used.

I believe there is no `gsutil` command that can show you the total size by storage class for a GCS bucket.

However, using the [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python) for Python, I made a script that does what you’re asking for:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import math

### SET THESE VARIABLES ###
PROJECT_ID = "" 
CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET = "" 
###########################

def _get_storage_client():
    return storage.Client(
        project=PROJECT_ID)

def convert_size(size_bytes):
   if size_bytes == 0:
       return "0 B"
   size_name = ("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB")
   i = int(math.floor(math.log(size_bytes, 1024)))
   p = math.pow(1024, i)
   s = round(size_bytes / p, 2)
   return "%s %s" % (s, size_name[i])

def size_by_class():
    client = _get_storage_client()
    bucket = client.bucket(CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs()

    size_multi_regional = size_regional = size_nearline = size_coldline = 0
    for blob in blobs:
        if blob.storage_class == "MULTI_REGIONAL":
            size_multi_regional = size_multi_regional + blob.size
        if blob.storage_class == "REGIONAL":
            size_regional = size_regional + blob.size
        if blob.storage_class == "NEARLINE":
            size_nearline = size_nearline + blob.size
        if blob.storage_class == "COLDLINE":
            size_coldline = size_coldline + blob.size

    print("MULTI_REGIONAL: "+str(convert_size(size_multi_regional))+"\n"+
            "REGIONAL: "+str(convert_size(size_regional)+"\n"+
            "NEARLINE: "+str(convert_size(size_nearline))+"\n"+
            "COLDLINE: "+str(convert_size(size_coldline))
            ))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    size_by_class()
```

To run this program from the [Google Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quickstart), make sure you have previously installed the [Client Library for Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#install_the_google_cloud_client_library_for_python) with:

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage
```

And in order to provide authentication credentials to the application code, you must point the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the location of the JSON file that contains your [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) key:

```
export `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"
```

Before running the script, set `PROJECT_ID` to the ID of your Project, and `CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET` to the name of your GCS Bucket.

Run the script with `python main.py`. Output should be something like:

```
MULTI_REGIONAL: 1.0 GB
REGIONAL: 300 MB
NEARLINE: 200 MB
COLDLINE: 10 MB
```

Comment: Hi @Maxima

Thank you for your response , This one is not solved my problem . This one i've already checked .I'll brief it once again, in my bucket i've multi-region , nearline and codeline . I would like to get size of the files for all types of storage class exists in the bucket .

If i've 50-GB in Multi-region ,
20 GB in NearLINE ,
1TB in codeline 
Like above i need response.

Comment: I misunderstood your initial inquiry then. I updated my answer. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi @Maxima,

It's solve my 50% of my problem , I've run the above code but i'm getting only nearline and code line size as expected but region and multi region size are . not coming . Please check it from ur end. Will you able to get all storage class sizes .

Comment: I filed a Feature Request on your behalf for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/119989059. As it is indeed something that can be useful when having multiple files with different Storage Classes. 
As for the issue you’re encountering, please verify that you have files in the GCS bucket that belong to the Storage Class ‘REGIONAL’ and ‘MULTI_REGIONAL’. I’ve tested this on my end and it worked. Nonetheless, I will take another look at the code and will come back to you with an update by Wednesday the latest.

Comment: I tested that in my bucket have 3 storage classes namely multi-region/region , Nearline and codline . 
Assume total size of the bucket is 100TB but as per the code i'm getting as 
Multi-regional/regional : 0 B
Neraline : 20 TB
Codeline : 70 TB 
but remaining size should falls either in multi-regional or regional .

Comment: @prasannaKumar Could you please state what is the use case for this feature on the Public Issue Tracker? Meaning, why is it useful for you? This is the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/119989059

Comment: @prasannaKumar I'm not getting the issue you're having, the program works correctly for me, showing the total size per Storage Class including Regional and Multi-regional. Perhaps your bucket or your files have a different configuration? I suggest creating another post regarding this.

Comment: @Maxima , I have tried the same code but for buckets it's working fine but for few buckets it's not showing as expected , see total size of bucket = size of muti-regional + regional + nearline + coldline.